# How to convert these GPS co-ordinates into valid Google Maps cordinates?

Tags: algorithm, gps, decoding

I am getting GPS values from my GPS logger like this:

```
3250193.00 E
1115573.00 N
```

What type of GPS co-ordinates are these? They look like UTM co-ordinates. How to decode them to proper Google Maps co-ordinates?

Comment: Do you have a reference for where on the Earth that data point refers to?

Comment: Two guesses - [32 50 19 30 E 11 15 57 30 N (Mexico)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/57+N.+30/@21.1658572,-86.8412092,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f4c2c0ca7307a6b:0xbdabcd8e89c04b4c) or [32.501930 E 11.155730 N (Africa)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/11%C2%B009'20.6%22N+32%C2%B030'07.0%22E/@11.15573,32.50193,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0). It can also be `111 55 73 00 N` or `111.5573 N`.

Comment: Yes... Its somewhere in Azad Kashmir (A territory in middle of China-India-Pakistan)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really a programming question.

Comment: @Dukeling It is programming, needs to decode the GPS and convert to google maps.. here I am asking for a pseudo-code

Comment: That is not UTM, UTM needs an Zone Id, which is missing here. So find out what "Coordinate Reference System" the logger uses, then post again. and it is not an WGS84 since Azad Kashmir is 32°N, 73E°; maybe some local coord system. Very strange setting or format for a logger.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinate conversion isn't a trivial thing - you need to know what format your data is in before you start, and then use the appropriate geographic transformation.

Intro to the topic:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002mq000000

Once you establish what data you're starting with you can use a library like GDAL to do the transformations:

[Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html)